# Migrating into process in Metasploit Meterpreter

Tags: process

I am using `kali linux metasploit framework`.

I have gained system admin access in [Metasploit Meterpreter](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/about-meterpreter/) using `getsystem`. Target computer is Windows 10 latest release.

I can list processes and do everything. When migrating to `winlogon` process this is what I get:

```
[*] Migrating from 16432 to 880...
[-] Error running command migrate: TypeError no implicit conversion of nil into String.
```

Have you tried something like this with success? This is something with encrypted credentials.

Comment: You're using the exploit toolkit Metasploit? Right?

Comment: @music2myear Google doesn't come up with any other results for `meterpreter`...

Comment: yes it is metasploit framework, latest version

Comment: @MichaelFrank Really? Then what is this I am seeing [when I do a search for it](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=METERPRETER&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: @JakeGould "any *other* results". :)

Comment: @MichaelFrank Oooh… Never mind.